# How to install Intel Java 11 on M2 Macbook?

Tags: java, apple-silicon

Because of a Java binary that only works on x86 architectures like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431573/how-to-handle-java-apps-lacking-arm-support-using-java-sdk-on-m1-mac), it seems I need to run the Intel versions of Java on my M2 Macbook using Rosetta.

I tried looking up how to do this, and after trying SDKMAN, and just running the Intel installer from Oracle, nothing seems to work.

Details of what I tried with SDKMAN:

1. Making a new terminal app that runs with Rosetta using [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/428769) instructions.

This works as expected:

```
 ~  arch                                                                                                                 
i386

 ~  uname -m                                                                                                             
x86_64
```

2. Edit `.sdkman/etc/config` to add `sdkman_rosetta2_compatible=false`
   (unsure if I should do this)
3. `sdk install java 11.0.20-ms`
   (unsure if Microsoft is the provider I should be using)
4. `` cat `which java` | file - ``

But this always shows an arm64 version.

How do I install an intel version of Java?

Comment: Can you explain the "gluegen" problem in your post, so folks don't need to follow that link to understand the reason here? Also to clarify: does this _have_ to be java 8, or is a later version fine, too (for instance, your point (3) installs java 11, not java 8)

Comment: On sister site AskDifferent.com I asked [*Force SDKMAN! to install for Intel versions on ARM (Apple Silicon) Macs?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/466518/17907)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  That discussion page says crashes result from gluegen_rt not containing an arm version in its [macos universal binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary).

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to skip SDKMAN! in this special case. Just download  a JDK installer for Intel macOS, and run the installer on your M1/M2/M3 Mac. Several vendors supply JDKs for macOS on Intel. These include Azul Systems, Microsoft, Adoptium, SAP, Amazon, IBM, Red Hat, Oracle, BellSoft, and more. If you don't have a favorite vendor, and don't need support, just go to [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) by the Eclipse Foundation. Navigate to find Intel Mac downloads.

Comment: https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?os=mac&arch=x64&version=8

Comment: As I said, I did run the Intel installer on my Mac, it complains about the incorrect architecture and closes. If there is a way around this I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I apologize, I meant install Java 11, not Java 8. I don't know why I get them mixed up quite often.

Comment: Do you have Rosetta 2 already installed?

Comment: @BasilBourque I ran `softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`, which should have installed it. Given I could make a copy of iTerm that runs with Rosetta I think it worked, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Re " I did run the Intel installer on my Mac, ..." At least [BellSoft's](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#jdk-11-lts) and Oracle's OpenJDK builds are available as TAR.GZ archives. Download and extract to a directory of your choice (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is probably a good choice). No installer required.

Comment: but remember that you'll have to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable manually, of course, and add the bin dir to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Behr suggested, extracting the Java downloaded as a tar.gz from https://jdk.java.net/archive/ seems to work for installing x86 Java on Apple Silicon. This did not solve my universal library issue, but that is out of scope at this point. Thanks for the help.